# you created new theme with html and css and integrated in all pages in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme

I have worked on HTML and CSS. I completed the page designs on HTML and CSS.

How to integrated all pages in Magento 2 ?

Comment: Can you please explain properly exactly what issue you are facing ?

Comment: Actually, my task is to create a theme using HTML and CSS ok and integrated with all Magento pages

Answer (score 0):

To create a new magento2 theme you can follow the developer documentation:

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html